# Exception thrown at 0x7C131F4C (ucrtbased.dll) in ICP LAB ASSIGNMENT PROJECT.exe: 0xC0000005

Tags: c

I was trying to print some array but it won't print no matter what.

Which part did I do wrong?

Is it the array?

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    char id[3]; ///sample data wanted to print
    id[0] = 'id1';
    id[1] = 'id2';
    id[2] = 'id3';
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s", id[i]); ///The error appeared here////
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You invoked *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type: `%s` expects an pointer to a null-terminated string while you passed `id[i]`, whose type is `char` (expanded to `int` here).

You can use `%c` to display the values of implementation-defined values of multi-character character literals.

Also The loop range is wrong as @abelenky says.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    char id[3]; ///sample data wanted to print
    id[0] = 'id1';
    id[1] = 'id2';
    id[2] = 'id3';
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        printf("%c", id[i]);
    }
}
```

Or do you mean this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    const char* id[3]; ///sample data wanted to print
    id[0] = "id1";
    id[1] = "id2";
    id[2] = "id3";
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n", id[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`i` starts at `1`, and goes to `3`:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 3; ++i)
```

But you set up your array so that valid indicies are `0`, `1`, and `2`.
`3` is not a valid index.

Convention C-loops always look like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
```

That is, they start at `0` and go while ***less than*** the size of the array.
Not ***less than or equal to***.  That is your mistake.

---

Next, each element of the array is a single character.
But you are trying to initialize them with 3-letters, such as: `id1`.
A single character can hold ONE LETTER ONLY, not a set of 3 letters.

You are trying to print them out using `%s`; but `%s` is for *strings*, not single characters.

---

Here is a corrected version of your program.

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    char* id[3];    // Declare strings, not characters.
    id[0] = "id1";  // Initialize each with a string
    id[1] = "id2";
    id[2] = "id3";
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)  // Set loop limit correctly.
    {
        printf("%s\n", id[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: int main()
{
    int i;
    const char* id[8], pass[8]; ///sample data wanted to print
    id[0] = "id1";
    id[1] = "id2";
    id[2] = "id3";
    pass[1] = "pass1";
    pass[2] = "pass2";
    pass[3] = "pass3";
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
     {
        printf("%s\n", pass[i]);
     }
}

Again the same error appeared

Comment: You set `id[0]`, but you never set `pass[0]`. Instead, you started with `pass[1] = "..."`
You must set `pass[0]` before you try to print it.